# Google Apps Scripts and Google Forms: which is the Class Form method for "Add title and description"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm coding a script in GAS that creates a form. I need to insert an "Add title and description" element in my form, like this one:

[image: Google Forms - Add title and description element]

but I cannot identify [the method in the Form class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) that inserts this specific element.

I need this "Add title and description" element because this is an informative piece, no answer needed from responders, so it cannot be the `addParagraphTextItem()` or the `addTextItem()`. And this is not related with new sections, so it cannot be the `addSectionHeaderItem()`.

---

Edit: The problem with the `addSectionHeaderItem()`

The goal is to have all *Titles and descriptions* in only one form page, so each of them will have one multiple choice question and the user can scroll all the descriptions up and down:

[image: Google forms - Good solution]

Using sections creates one form page for each section and the user is obliged to navigate through the different pages. This is not the solution I am looking for:

[image: Google form - Bad solution 0]
[image: Google form - Bad solution 1]
[image: Google form - Bad solution 2]

Comment: Hello @LaosLos, I am not sure I understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. The `addSectionHeaderItem()` looks like it will solve your issue - check [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/wWp4ZUx). Would you mind providing more details?

Comment: Hi @ale13, thanks for your feedback. I have updated the original question with some clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is. Some methods in Form class are not named properly and mislead a little bit.

The "Add title and description" functionality is coded under the `addSectionHeaderItem()` method, and the "Add section" functionality is coded under the `addPageBreakItem()` method.

So, some code like:

```
  var form = FormApp.create('test_form');
  form.setTitle('Test Form')
      .setDescription('Form description');

  var section_item = form.addPageBreakItem()
  section_item.setTitle('Section Title');

  var title_and_description_item = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
  title_and_description_item.setTitle('Some title')
                            .setHelpText('Some description');
```

gives that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't seem to  be a way to use  "Add title and description" functionality programmatically. Consider creating a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) to let Google know that you're interested in this feature.

Comment: You may [edit] this answer or create a new answer with your feature request link to publicise the request